# lil-Sparse matrix row splitting

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix (lil) implemented in Python with scipy, which comprises of Users on one axis, and songs they played on the other. So each row is a linked list of the songs that user has played.

I need to split each row ( user's songs ) so i have training and test data, but I'm unsure of how to do this. Sorry, im new to python, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show an example of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split)